# UtcNow to human/system friendly string

Tags: c#, datetime, azure

I will be using UtcNow values as part of a composite key on Azure. I'd like to convert the date/time to something that is both human and computer friendly. Something like this: 2016021416512345 => 2016/02/14 4:51:23 PM

I can create a helper method that can simply take the current UTC time and parse its components e.g. Year, Month, etc. and give me this but I wanted to get some suggestions.

By the way, I did think about using ticks but that's not very human friendly.

Is there a nice and elegant way to produce what I want other than using a helper method that I mentioned?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for DateTime (especially format strings)?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I can just set the format I want and get the result as a string. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case I need a `DateTime` as a string in a canonical and stable format I usually use `dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.fff")`. That's simple enough and sortable.